# Installing Eclipse without changing the PATH env variable

Tags: eclipse, environment-variables

Is it possible to specify the jvm that the eclipse installer will use? I'm getting the error "Version 1.7.0_67 of the JVM is not suitable for this product. Version: 1.8 or greater is required".

I want to install eclipse oxygen and I have jdk 8, but I don't want to mess with the PATH environment variable that is currently pointing to jre 7, because I fear it may confuse other programs. Is there any way to do this?

---

**Update:**

I tried creating an eclipse-inst.ini file as suggested and placed it in the same directory as the installer (note, I didn't edit anything, since there was no existing file).

Tried a number of options for the second line (of course not all at the same time like below):

```
-vm
C:/zIMC/imc-dev-1.8/jdk8/jre/bin/javaw.exe
C:/zIMC/imc-dev-1.8/jdk8/bin/javaw.exe
C:/zIMC/imc-dev-1.8/jdk8/bin/java.exe
C:/zIMC/imc-dev-1.8/jdk8/bin/
C:/zIMC/imc-dev-1.8/jdk8/jre/bin/server/jvm.dll
```

Also tried most of them with backslash instead. The last one is from the eclipse.ini of my old installation, which is using jdk7. None of them works, all still give exactly the same message then the installer is run.

Comment: See https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#Specifying_the_JVM (for `eclipse-inst.ini` it is the same as for `eclipse.ini`)

Comment: I tried making the eclipse-inst.ini file with only the -vm argument in it and it didn't work.

Comment: Could you please add the content of your edited `eclipse-inst.ini` file to your question?

Comment: You have to edit the existing `eclipse-inst.ini`. On Windows the Eclipse Installer is a self-extracting ZIP file which extract the application with the `eclipse-inst.ini` file into a temp folder. If you only want to install a single Eclipse package, I recommend directly [download the ZIP of the Eclipse package](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/eclipse-packages/) you want, unzip it and edit the [`eclipse.ini`](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#Specifying_the_JVM).

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue
Download zip version of eclipse,
Once deployed open text file at root folder eclipse.ini
Add the following lines:

```
-vm
C:/java/jdk1.8.0_144/jre/bin  (put correct path for your jvm here)
```

I added the lines after --launcher.appendVmargs , but i am not sure if that makes any difference.